# locate many pictures in one page

Tags: floats, numbering

I make problem sheets for my class. I want that problems will be automaticly count by Latex. second problem I can not place picture at the right side of the problem.

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\par
 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.9,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.9,2);
     \draw (2.1,2) -- (3,2)-- (3.9,2);
      \draw (0.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,2.2);
\draw (3.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (5.1,2.2);
\draw (3,2) -- (3,1.4);
\draw (3,0.6) -- (3,0);
\draw (3,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

\draw (0.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,0.2);
\draw (3.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (5.1,0.2);

\draw (2.1,0) -- (3,0)-- (3.2,0) -- node[above] {\large K} (3.6,0.2);
\draw (3.7,0) -- (3.9,0);
\draw (5.1,2) -- (6,2) -- (6,0) -- (5.1,0);

\draw (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) -- (2.7,-0.5);
\draw (6,0) -- (6,-0.5) -- (3.3,-0.5);
\draw (2.75,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
\draw (3.25,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

1. Схема, изображённая на рис. 9.2, состоит из четырёх резисторов,          идеального амперметра и 
ключа К. Сопротивления всех резисторов указаны на рисунке. Если ключ замкнут, амперметр 
 показывает значение Ii = 0,5 А. Какое значение силы тока 1г будет   показывать амперметр, если 
 ключ разомкнуть? Напряжение в цепи в обоих случаях одинаковое.\\

 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
 \centering
\draw (0.4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.4,2);
\draw (1.6,2) -- (2,2)-- (2.4,2);
\draw (0.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (1.6,2.2);
\draw (2.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (3.6,2.2);
\draw (2,2) -- (2,1.4);
\draw (2,0.6) -- (2,0);
\draw (2,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

\draw (0.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (1.6,0.2);
\draw (2.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (3.6,0.2);

\draw (1.6,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.4,0);
\draw (3.6,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (3.6,0);


\draw (0,1) -- (-0.3,1);
 \draw (-0.35,1)circle(0.05cm);

 \draw (4,1) -- (4.4,1);
 \draw (4.4,0.8) rectangle node {\large 5R} (5.6,1.2);
 \draw (5.6,1) -- (6,1);
 \draw (6.05,1)circle(0.05cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{wrapfigure}
  2. Определите показания амперметра, если через резистор 5R течёт ток 48 А.   Ответ дать в
  амперах. Амперметр считать идеальным.
 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \centering
\draw (0.4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.4,2);
\draw (1.6,2) -- (2,2)-- (2.4,2);
\draw (0.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (1.6,2.2);
\draw (2.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (3.6,2.2);
\draw (2,2) -- (2,1.4);
\draw (2,0.6) -- (2,0);
\draw (2,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large V};

\draw (0.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (1.6,0.2);
\draw (2.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (3.6,0.2);

\draw (1.6,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.4,0);
\draw (3.6,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (3.6,0);


\draw (0,1) -- (-0.3,1);
 \draw (-0.35,1)circle(0.05cm);

 \draw (4,1) -- (4.4,1);
 \draw (4.4,0.8) rectangle node {\large R} (5.6,1.2);
 \draw (5.6,1) -- (6,1);
 \draw (6.05,1)circle(0.05cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{wrapfigure}


3. Определите, к какому внешнему напряжению подключена схема, если вольтметр показывает
U = 5 В. Ответ дать в вольтах, округлить до целых. Сопротивление вольтметра гораздо больше
сопротивлений резисторов.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0.5,0)--(0,0) -- (0,0.9);
\draw (0,1.1) -- (0,2)--(4.4,2)--(4.4,1.4);

\draw (-0.2,0.9) -- (0.2,0.9);
\draw (-0.4,1.1) -- (0.4,1.1);

 \draw (0.9,0)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $A_{1}$};
\draw (1.3,0) -- (1.8,0);
\draw (2.2,0)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $V_{1}$};
\draw (3.1,2) -- (3.1,1.4);
\draw (2.6,0) -- (3.1,0)--(4.4,0)--(4.4,0.6);
\draw (3.1,0) -- (3.1,0.6);
 \draw (3.1,1)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $A_{2}$};
\draw (4.4,1)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $V_{2}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
4. В схему включены два микроамперметра Al, А2 и два одинаковых вольтметра VI,
V2. Приборы показывают следующие значения * —физических величин: 1\ - 100  мкА, h = 99 мкА, V\
 = 10 В. Найти показание вольтметра Vi.

 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0)--(6,0);
 \draw (1.5,0)--(1.5,0.6);
 \draw (1.2,0.6) rectangle node {\large $R_{1}$} (1.8,2);
 \draw (1.5,2) -- (1.5,2.6);
 \draw (4.2,0.6) rectangle node {\large $R_{3}$} (4.8,2);

 \draw (1.5,2.6)--(2.3,2.6);
\draw (2.3,2.3) rectangle node {\large $R_{2}$} (3.7,2.9);
 \draw (3.7,2.6)--(4.5,2.6);
\draw (1.5,2) -- (1.5,2.6);
\draw (4.5,2.6) -- (4.5,2);
\draw (4.5,0.6) -- (4.5,0);
\draw (0,2.6) -- (1.5,2.6);
\draw (4.5,2.6) -- (6,2.6);

  \draw (6.05,2.6)circle(0.05cm);
  \draw (6.05,0)circle(0.05cm);
  \draw (-0.05,2.6)circle(0.05cm);
  \draw (-0.05,0)circle(0.05cm);
  \node[label=below:\rotatebox{-90}{вход}] at (0,1.9) {};
  \node[label=below:\rotatebox{-90}{выход}] at (5.8,2.1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{wrapfigure}


5. Если на вход электрической цепи (рис.2) подать напряжение 100 В, то    напряжение на
 выходе будет равным 30 В. Амперметр с очень малым сопротивлением,  присоединенный к выходу
 цепи, показывает силу тока 1А. Если напряжение 100
В подать на выход цепи, то напряжение на входе
 будет 15 В. Найти сопротивления резисторов $R_{1}, R_{2},R_{3}$




\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

**I want to get:**

[image]

Comment: It would help to provide a full MWE, including the document class and all needed packages.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't wrapping the text AROUND the figure, just use minipages.

It helps to put the picture into a savebox first.  That is what wrapfigure does, since your pictures are wider than 3cm.

Without your babel and encoding setup, the Russian text is being ignored.  I assume you can fix that a lot easier than me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0.9,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.9,2);
     \draw (2.1,2) -- (3,2)-- (3.9,2);
      \draw (0.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,2.2);
\draw (3.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (5.1,2.2);
\draw (3,2) -- (3,1.4);
\draw (3,0.6) -- (3,0);
\draw (3,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

\draw (0.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,0.2);
\draw (3.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (5.1,0.2);

\draw (2.1,0) -- (3,0)-- (3.2,0) -- node[above] {\large K} (3.6,0.2);
\draw (3.7,0) -- (3.9,0);
\draw (5.1,2) -- (6,2) -- (6,0) -- (5.1,0);

\draw (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) -- (2.7,-0.5);
\draw (6,0) -- (6,-0.5) -- (3.3,-0.5);
\draw (2.75,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
\draw (3.25,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}% Note: \linewidth < \textwidth
Схема, изображённая на рис. 9.2, состоит из четырёх резисторов,          идеального амперметра и 
ключа К. Сопротивления всех резисторов указаны на рисунке. Если ключ замкнут, амперметр 
 показывает значение Ii = 0,5 А. Какое значение силы тока 1г будет   показывать амперметр, если 
 ключ разомкнуть? Напряжение в цепи в обоих случаях одинаковое.\\
\end{minipage}\hfil
\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\ht\tempbox}{\usebox{\tempbox}}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0.4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.4,2);
\draw (1.6,2) -- (2,2)-- (2.4,2);
\draw (0.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (1.6,2.2);
\draw (2.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (3.6,2.2);
\draw (2,2) -- (2,1.4);
\draw (2,0.6) -- (2,0);
\draw (2,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

\draw (0.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (1.6,0.2);
\draw (2.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (3.6,0.2);

\draw (1.6,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.4,0);
\draw (3.6,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (3.6,0);


\draw (0,1) -- (-0.3,1);
 \draw (-0.35,1)circle(0.05cm);

 \draw (4,1) -- (4.4,1);
 \draw (4.4,0.8) rectangle node {\large 5R} (5.6,1.2);
 \draw (5.6,1) -- (6,1);
 \draw (6.05,1)circle(0.05cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}
Определите показания амперметра, если через резистор 5R течёт ток 48 А.   Ответ дать в
  амперах. Амперметр считать идеальным.
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\ht\tempbox}{\usebox{\tempbox}}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0.4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.4,2);
\draw (1.6,2) -- (2,2)-- (2.4,2);
\draw (0.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (1.6,2.2);
\draw (2.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (3.6,2.2);
\draw (2,2) -- (2,1.4);
\draw (2,0.6) -- (2,0);
\draw (2,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large V};

\draw (0.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (1.6,0.2);
\draw (2.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (3.6,0.2);

\draw (1.6,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.4,0);
\draw (3.6,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (3.6,0);


\draw (0,1) -- (-0.3,1);
 \draw (-0.35,1)circle(0.05cm);

 \draw (4,1) -- (4.4,1);
 \draw (4.4,0.8) rectangle node {\large R} (5.6,1.2);
 \draw (5.6,1) -- (6,1);
 \draw (6.05,1)circle(0.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}
Определите, к какому внешнему напряжению подключена схема, если вольтметр показывает
U = 5 В. Ответ дать в вольтах, округлить до целых. Сопротивление вольтметра гораздо больше
сопротивлений резисторов.
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\ht\tempbox}{\usebox{\tempbox}}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0.5,0)--(0,0) -- (0,0.9);
\draw (0,1.1) -- (0,2)--(4.4,2)--(4.4,1.4);

\draw (-0.2,0.9) -- (0.2,0.9);
\draw (-0.4,1.1) -- (0.4,1.1);

 \draw (0.9,0)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $A_{1}$};
\draw (1.3,0) -- (1.8,0);
\draw (2.2,0)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $V_{1}$};
\draw (3.1,2) -- (3.1,1.4);
\draw (2.6,0) -- (3.1,0)--(4.4,0)--(4.4,0.6);
\draw (3.1,0) -- (3.1,0.6);
 \draw (3.1,1)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $A_{2}$};
\draw (4.4,1)circle(0.4cm) node {\large $V_{2}$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}
В схему включены два микроамперметра Al, А2 и два одинаковых вольтметра VI,
V2. Приборы показывают следующие значения * —физических величин: 1\ - 100  мкА, h = 99 мкА, V\
 = 10 В. Найти показание вольтметра Vi.
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\ht\tempbox}{\usebox{\tempbox}}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0)--(6,0);
 \draw (1.5,0)--(1.5,0.6);
 \draw (1.2,0.6) rectangle node {\large $R_{1}$} (1.8,2);
 \draw (1.5,2) -- (1.5,2.6);
 \draw (4.2,0.6) rectangle node {\large $R_{3}$} (4.8,2);

 \draw (1.5,2.6)--(2.3,2.6);
\draw (2.3,2.3) rectangle node {\large $R_{2}$} (3.7,2.9);
 \draw (3.7,2.6)--(4.5,2.6);
\draw (1.5,2) -- (1.5,2.6);
\draw (4.5,2.6) -- (4.5,2);
\draw (4.5,0.6) -- (4.5,0);
\draw (0,2.6) -- (1.5,2.6);
\draw (4.5,2.6) -- (6,2.6);

  \draw (6.05,2.6)circle(0.05cm);
  \draw (6.05,0)circle(0.05cm);
  \draw (-0.05,2.6)circle(0.05cm);
  \draw (-0.05,0)circle(0.05cm);
  \node[label=below:\rotatebox{-90}{вход}] at (0,1.9) {};
  \node[label=below:\rotatebox{-90}{выход}] at (5.8,2.1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\tempbox-\columnsep}
Если на вход электрической цепи (рис.2) подать напряжение 100 В, то    напряжение на
 выходе будет равным 30 В. Амперметр с очень малым сопротивлением,  присоединенный к выходу
 цепи, показывает силу тока 1А. Если напряжение 100
В подать на выход цепи, то напряжение на входе
 будет 15 В. Найти сопротивления резисторов $R_{1}, R_{2},R_{3}$
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\ht\tempbox}{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]